# ADB command for identifying USB port

Tags: android, usb, adb, usbserial, android-usb

I want to know the adb command for getting USB port number of connected android device. Please help me to configure my device with android.

Thanks in Advance

Answer (score 4):

The following command lists the devices with corresponding usb port.

```
adb devices -l
```